# Bugzilla LDAP Authentication troubleshooting

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, bugzilla

I'm fairly new to linux server administration, but I've "successfully" spun up a bugzilla server.

System: Ubuntu 12.04, mysql-server, bugzilla-4.4.2

On my Admin account I have configured Parameters->LDAP.  I have double and triple checked my configuration.  I'm looking for a way to troubleshoot (like error logs, or a way to catch errors thrown).  Please be specific with log information if you can.  If you can give me the location of any logs I can look through that would be very helpful.

Comment: start with your LDAP access log. You should be able to see the search performed by `bugzilla` and compare it with a manual `ldapsearch`, for example.

Comment: You should put this as an answer since it did answer my question, and I'll mark it as correct.  Thank you for the help.